# Firefox not loading images works great on ie and chrome

Tags: html, css, image, firefox

I got this website, http://pure-soft.net/web. The problem is that Firefox is not loading images; Chrome and IE works fine .

What's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Firefox 28 loads the images with no problems for me.

Comment: i did try it on 2 pc's not working :(

Comment: Well I'm on Mac, so I'm no help here

Comment: Works fine. Firefox 29.0

Comment: Works for me in Windows 8, FF 28.0